# How to Show List of Data on Html Form

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a online store site that has a shopping cart. The problem is in filling the shipment city.

The goal is that, when the user wants to fill in the shipment city, it will show the city in the list instantly (it's hard to explain).

You can try it at http://www.brandedwatch.co.id

Go to shopping cart and try to fill "Kota Tujuan" (it means shipment city). When you type in "jak", it will automatically show data from MySQL where the name is like "jak", for example "jakarta".

It's like giving a suggestion or auto complete.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for people to be able to give you meaningful answers, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/), or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/). This will help people understand where the problem is.

Comment: @AndrewMyers thanks your correction, i will do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you require auto suggests, when a user enters his requirement.

The Sql Query would something be like,

```
select * from cityTableName
where cityNameField like 'usersInput%'
limit 10
```

**Or**

if you want more appropriate and efficient results you can go with `MATCH AGAINST`

to know more about `MatchAgainst` : visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on pre-populated select list 
https://select2.github.io/ This inbuilt jQuery has the feature you are looking for. You have to use AJAX to fetch lists on it.

Here are some working examples:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html